# Getting asked twice to insert integer

Tags: c

I have some homework to do for the University, and since I'm a beginner I don't know how to code yet. So, there are 10 tests with the grade of each being between 0 and 10. I have to make sure that I don't get any negative number or a number greater than 10. while running the code I have to put 2 numbers in order to proceed to the next one, when, I clearly want just the one saved to A[i]. I hope you understand even though I can't even explain the problem. :)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A[10]; 
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 1; i<11; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %d grade \n", i);
        scanf("%d", &j);
        if (j<=10 && j>=0)
         A[i] = j;
        else
         printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10\n");
         scanf("%d", &j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for writing beyond the bounds of an object.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47314442/edit) to include more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error are usually off-topic. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: In this case this is a typo of indexing from 1 to 10 instead of 0 to 9, and missing the braces for the block inside `else`.

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed, which means the first element of `A` is `A[0]`, not `A[1]`

Comment: A major requirement to writing software is to have a clearly understood set of requirements.  It is a total waste of time to write code without first having that clear understanding.  Suggest determining what the actual requirements are, then edit the question to clearly state those requirements.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10\n");`  is misleading as it excludes 0 and 10.  Suggest: `printf("Enter a number in the range 0...10\n");`

Answer (score 1):

#### Why 2 inputs?

What you wrote

```
     else
     printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10\n");
     scanf("%d", &j);
```

which is same as

```
     else {
     printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10\n");
     }
     scanf("%d", &j);
```

What you want is:-

```
    else {
     printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10\n");
     scanf("%d", &j);
    }
```

This is what is told very early stage. It is clear this is why you need to enter 2 numbers even when you are giving correct input.

---

#### Undefined behavior:-

Also you have 10 location in `A` why write at `A[10]`. C arrays are 0-indexed. You are dealing with undefined behavior.

```
for ( i = 0; i<10; i++)
```

#### Error in logic?

What happens when a user gives two times a wrong input? You need to use a `while` loop. ( You can't expect all user to be right the second time).

#### Scanf returns something ...

Check the return type of `scanf` to check if the `scanf` call is doing what you expect it to do.

---

Other bits that I will tell you will be use `size_t` in the looping variable.

Comment: Wow, that was simple enough! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, adding braces:

`//     V-- brace
     else {
           printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10\n");
         scanf("%d", &j);
     }
   //^-- brace`

shoud solve the problem you described in your message.  Without the braces, only the first thing after the `else` is part of the conditional.  Therefore, `scanf` was always being executed, whether or not the number was between 0 and 10.

I also agree with the other answers --- zero-indexing and for-loop bounds are important.  **Edit**  Specifically, in C arrays the first element is 0.  Thus you are better off to number your tests 0..9 instead of 1..10.  You should also name your variables what they are, thus:

```
int which_test;
for (which_test = 0; which_test < 10; ++which_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

arrays start at index 0 in C so your for loop should go be `for(i=0;i<10;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

`A[i] = j;` invoked undefined behaviour because C does not check array bound.

**C11 J.2 Undefined behavior**

> - Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an integer type produces a result that points just beyond
>     the array object and is used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that
>     is evaluated (6.5.6).

In your code size of array `A` is `10*sizeof(int)` bytes. So, you can store array elements 0 to 9.

Comment: the statement: *In your code size of array A is 10 bytes.*  is only true if a `int` is one byte.   On modern CPUs, each `int` is 4 or 8 bytes (32bit or 64bit architecture)  So the array `A` has 10 entries and each entry is (4 or 8) bytes. So the actual number of bytes in the array is 40 or 80, not 10

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. You should try this using do-while loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A[10]; 
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        do{
            printf("Enter %d grade \n", i+1);
            scanf("%d", &A[i]);
        }while(A[i]<0 || A[i]>10);
    }
}
```

Comment: this statement: `while(A[i]<0 || A[i]>10);`  says to exit the loop if the number entered by the user is in the range 0...10.  That is not what the OPs question asks for.

Comment: @user3629249 This condition says to keep taking input for a particular grade value if user has entered value *less than 0* or *greater than 10*  as OP wants to have *grade of each being between 0 and 10*

Comment: your right, I misunderstood what the OP was trying to do at this particular code block.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely here:

```
    if (j<=10 && j>=0)
     A[i] = j;
    else
     printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10\n");
     scanf("%d", &j);
```

There are no braces around the `else` clause, so only the first statement after the  `else` applies to it.  The above is the same as:

```
    if (j<=10 && j>=0) {
     A[i] = j;
    } else {
     printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10\n");
    }
    scanf("%d", &j);
```

So the second `scanf` is being executed every time.

Always put braces around `if`/`else`, `for`, and `while` blocks:

```
    if (j<=10 && j>=0) {
       A[i] = j;
    } else {
       printf("Enter a number between 0 and 10\n");
       scanf("%d", &j);
    }
```

Also, your array `int A[10];` has a total of 10 elements with indexes ranging from 0 to 9.  Your `for` loop uses indexes from 1 to 10, so you end up writing past the end of the array.  Fix this to use the proper indexes:

```
for ( i = 0; i<10; i++)
```